# How to resolve "No results were returned by the query" exception in Postgres while using JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi i am building a rest service to delete an entity from PostgreSQL using JPA.
And the code is:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepo  extends JpaRepository<Question, Long>{
    @Query(value = "delete from testmodel c where c.id in ?1 and c.name=?2",
            nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteModel(List<Long> ids, String text);
}
```

The code is working fine, the entries got deleted from PostgreSQL but i am getting the following exception in terminal.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:107) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
```

When i searched for this exception i got a suggestion to use executeUpdate instead of executeQuery.

Since i am using JPA i don't know how to replace executeQuery with executeUpdate

Any help would be greatful.

Comment: Try to add a `@Modifying` annotation .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add `@Modifying` to declare that it is an update query and you don't expect a result back from the DB

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepo  extends JpaRepository<Question, Long>{
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "delete from testmodel c where c.id in ?1 and c.name=?2",
            nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteModel(List<Long> ids, String text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think modifying queries must be annotated with an extra
use this `@Modifying` since u r modifying the query and not expecting any resultset